# Updating content in android without submitting a new apk file

Tags: android, feed

How do news apps update their newsfeed with new news? Do they submit new apk files to google play everyday? or how do they do it? Is there a framework they use.? Please anyone with knowledge of this , please help fill me in, Thanks

Comment: They do it using a server.

Comment: use mongolab and Amazon they give free Sandboxs for developers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any app that has data that is updated uses some type of server API to fetch new data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Answer (score 0):

They use Web Services to provide data to update and the App just request this via internet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service